# Create a simple pie chart jpg or png from CSV

Tags: r, plot, pie-chart

I am trying to build a `jpg` or `png` file, that creates a pie cart from a `CSV` file like this:

```
Apples;2
Bananas;6
Oranges;10
```

As I am new and most examples have many complex options, I am looking for an easy example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As below:

```
#data
slices <- c(2, 6, 10)
lbls <- c("Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges")

#plot and save as png
png(file = "myPie.png", bg = "transparent")
pie(slices, labels = lbls, main="Pie Chart of Fruits")
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Ihave now created a bash script that makes the r program from my csv data file. Biggest problem was running the script as a cronjob...  Instead of running the script like 'R --file="script.r"' I have to run 'DISPLAY=:1 R --file="script.r"'